# Having trouble with python simple code running in console

Tags: python, python-2.7

I ran this code.Then it displayed the follwing in the console.

> Traceback (most recent call last): File "", line 13, in  NameError: name 'r' is not defined

```
import math

p = int(raw_input("Please enter deposit amount: \n"))
i = int(raw_input("Please input interest rate: \n"))
t = int(raw_input("Please insert number of years of the invesment: \n"))
interest = raw_input("Do you want a simple or compound interest ? \n")

A = p(1+r*t)
B = p(1+r)^t

if interest == "simple":
    print int(float(A))
elif interest == "compound":
    print int(float(B))
```

Comment: your interest variable is called `i` not `r` and `p(1+r*t)` is not legal syntax given `p` is an `int`. Python's power operator is `**` not `^`. Wow, so many errors in so few lines - perhaps a beginners course in python is appropriate. (and I'll assume the indentation issues are just post errors).

Answer (score 2):

There were multiple errors and indentation problem ;I *commented* them where you made mistakes:

```
p = int(raw_input("Please enter deposit amount: \n"))
r = int(raw_input("Please input interest rate: \n")) #rename i to r
t = int(raw_input("Please insert number of years of the investment: \n"))
interest = raw_input("Do you want a simple or compound interest ? \n")

A = p*(1+r*t) #multiply p with ()
B = p*(1+r)**t #same as B

 #** is power

if interest == "simple":
    print (float(A)) # you dont need to cast the float again to int
else: #since there is no other conditions it's obvious to print compound 
    print(float(B))# you dont need to cast the float again to int
```

Comment: "So it should be" code that still has multiple errors and would not even compile?

Comment: yes it does not compile. Im suppose to make an Investment calculator. @tobias_k

Comment: @Duvall912 sorry my bad, I got it working.There were many errors,See my comments .Hope it helps.

Comment: I'm afraid it's still not correct. `^t` should be `**t` (you don't want to xor with `t`)

Comment: @Achilles its auppose to be a float where I divide the value with 100.

Comment: You don't have to convert it to float as it will print a float and if it doesn't,then just :print (float(A)):convert it.

Answer (score 1):

If you store the interest rate in `i` you should not use `r` in the formula some lines later.