# Having trouble converting result produced into a float with python

Tags: python, python-2.7

I am trying to get a float value but it keeps on giving me a decimal value as an answer.

```
import math

p = int(raw_input("Please enter deposit amount: \n"))
r = int(raw_input("Please input interest rate: \n"))
t = int(raw_input("Please insert number of years of the investment: \n"))
interest = raw_input("Do you want a simple or compound interest ? \n")

A = p*(1+r*t) 
B = p*(1+r)^t 

if interest == "simple":
    print (float(A/100))
else:
    print(float(B/100))
```

Comment: if you use Python 2 and `A` is integer then `A/100` gives integer. You need `A/100.0` or `float(A)/100`

Comment: Aside from the integral division issue, you are using the wrong exponentiation operator. it is `**` in Python.

Comment: @shash678: OP didn't even bother to correct the mistakes that were pointed out in that previous question ... :/ (And, so I see, [the one before that](http://stackoverflow.com/q/40979415/2564301)...)

Comment: I'm suppose to convert the interest and not the answer. I tried putting it by the variable then it returned the following exception.
@RadLexus


r = int(raw_input("Please input interest rate: \n")/100)

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 4, in <module>
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for /: 'str' and 'int'

Answer (score 4):

`float(A/100)` first calculates A/100, which are both ints, so the result is an int, and only then converts to float. Instead you could use:

```
float(A)/100
```

or:

```
A/100.
```

Comment: It still gives me an int. I need to return a float. @Ni

Comment: the first one didnt work for me but the second one ran perfectly.Why is that ?

Answer (score 0):

Here is the problem. In python2 the division between integers gives another integer (this is not true in python3).

```
42 / 100 # return 0
```

The solution is to keep one to float.

```
42 / 100.0 #return 0.42
```